# Sympy parse_expr with variables and == returning False

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I'm trying to parse some basic user entered boolean expressions containing symbols that will be filled in later.
I'm parsing to gather the symbols and make sure the logic is valid (ie, matched braces, double equal vs single, etc).
I'm having trouble with expressions that contain equal checks.
Short of pre-parsing to remove them, is there any way to keep sympy from returning False?

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
print(parse_expr('foo < 0', evaluate=False))
print(parse_expr('(foo < 0) & (foo > bar)', evaluate=False))
print(parse_expr('(foo < 0) & (foo > bar) & (baz == 0)', evaluate=False))
```

Results

```
foo < 0
(foo > bar) & (foo < 0)  ...reordered, but intact
False  ...including the == check caused the whole symbolic expression to be lost
```

Answer (score 1):

Sympy interprets the `==` operator differently than you are expecting. It evaluates if two expressions have the same form, not if they are equal. See [this entry in the "gotchas" section of the docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#double-equals-signs).

You may want `sympy.Eq(baz, 0)`, or something similar.

Comment: I've seen that post.  It doesn't help me with using parse_expr() though.

Comment: It means that you will have to process the string before parsing if you want to capture the intended meaning of `==`.

Comment: That's what I meant by "Short of pre-parsing"

Answer (score 1):

There exists a [`convert_equals_signs`](https://docs.sympy.org/1.4/_modules/sympy/parsing/sympy_parser.html) transformator for `parse_expr`, but sometimes it seems to be [conflicting](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/9255) with the assignment operator. It only works with a single equal sign, and with a constant at the left. Also nesting can be a problem. A similar `convert_equality_operators` seems to be removed again from the code (probably the conflicts couldn't be solved easily).

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr, standard_transformations, convert_equals_signs

print(parse_expr('foo < 0', evaluate=False))
print(parse_expr('(foo < 0) & (foo > bar)', evaluate=False))
print(parse_expr('(foo < 0) & (foo > bar) & (0 = baz)', evaluate=False,
                 transformations=(standard_transformations + (convert_equals_signs,))))
```